# How to open link in external browser instead of in-app (instagram, IPhone)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cross-browser, instagram

if I have a link in Instagram-app, the link opens up an in-app browser either from iOS...
Is it possible to open up an external browser instead?
I tried a lot of things, like using window.open with _blank, _system, _self and

```
  <script>
   if(navigator.userAgent.includes("Instagram")){
       window.location.href = "https://mywebsite.com/DummyBytes";
   }
  </script>
```

this, too

my enviroment

- ruby2.4.5
- rails
- javascript
- jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.open`

```
  <script>
   if(navigator.userAgent.includes("Instagram")){
       window.open("https://mywebsite.com/DummyBytes")
   }
  </script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: window.open No longer supported by ios14.